# not add same product on table again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how i can add a product but, **when i select same product again**, show a message that the product already was been added? and, after this, add all the products in a input hidden as value like this: "[product][0]".

my first script
http://jsfiddle.net/Gp33X/

Simple HTML:

```
<select id="lista_produtos">
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
    <option>option 4</option>
    <option>option 5</option>
</select>
<input type="number" id="quant_produtos">
<button id="add_produto">ADD</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table border="1" width="100%" id="cesta_produtos">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>product</td>
            <td>quant</td>
            <td>remove</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#add_produto').on('click', function () {

    var $table = $('#cesta_produtos tbody'), // Products table
        $list = $('#lista_produtos').val(), // Select list
        $quant = $('#quant_produtos').val(), // Quant field
        $remove = "<a href='#' class='del_produto'>x</a>"; // Link to remove the product

    // Insert the selected product on the table
    $table.append("<tr><td>" + $list + "</td><td>" + $quant + "</td><td>" + $remove + "</td></tr>");

});

// Remove the product from table
$(document).on('click', '.del_produto', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var dialog = confirm("Are you sure you want remove this product?");

    if (dialog == true) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    } else {
        console.log("produto removido");
    }
});
```

Comment: Not an answer, but your syntax is a little sloppy; that second `<tbody>` should be `</tbody>` which is causing a bug in your JFiddle.

Comment: i see, my original source are right, was only in the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `selectedProducts` array and then check if the newly selected product is already in that array using [jQuery's inArray function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/).

```
var selectedProducts = [];

$('#add_produto').on('click', function () {
    var $table = $('#cesta_produtos tbody'), // Products table
        list = $('#lista_produtos').val(), // Select list
        quant = $('#quant_produtos').val(), // Quant field
        remove = "<a href='#' class='del_produto'>x</a>"; // Link to remove the product

    if ($.inArray(list, selectedProducts)) {
        console.log(list + ' was already selected');
        return;
    } else {
        // Insert the selected product on the table
        $table.append("<tr><td>" + list + "</td><td>" + quant + "</td><td>" + remove + "</td></tr>");
        selectedProducts.push(list);
    }
});
```

Also, I removed the prefixed `$` from the names `list`, `quant`, and `remove`. They are not jQuery objects and many developers would find that confusing. Also, two items are being added but Rufism answers that issue.

Oh, and be sure to remove the item from the array if necessary.

Comment: In this case you also need to add to the selectedProduct and just not append it to the html tiwh a selectedProducts.push(list); or whatever value you want to store in the selectedProducts to distinguish the items from each other

Comment: have fiddle my friend?

Answer (score -1):

Two copies of whatever option you are adding are being produced because your  doesn't have a closing tag. Therefore, when you select your table

```
$table  = $('#cesta_produtos, tbody'), // Products table
```

you get two  elements to append to. Just change

```
<tbody>

<tbody>
```

to

```
</tbody>
```

Comment: I already addressed that in a comment; this doesn't answer his question at all.

Comment: my original source are right, was only in the fiddle.